# I am having troubles with a string

Tags: python

It is giving me this error code when i run it

```
Good day sir: Dog play music
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Python34\My_Friend\test.py", line 23, in <module>
    os.startfile(song)

TypeError: Can't convert 'NoneType' object to str implicitly
```

---

```
if(next == "Dog play music"):
    music = ['Asshole.mp3', 'Berzerk.mp3', 'Brainless.mp3',
    'Rap_God.mp3',  'Rabbit_Run.mp3','Lose_Yourself.mp3', 'Survival.mp3']

    song = random.shuffle(music)
    stop = False
    while(stop == False):
            os.startfile(song)
            stop = True
            user = input(song + " has been played: ")
            if(user == "Dog im done"):
                     os.startfile('test.py')
                     os.close('test.py')
            if(user == "Dog play next"):
                     stop = False
```

Comment: I think you want `random.choice()`, not `random.shuffle()`.

Comment: As a side note: you don't need to write `while(stop == False)`; use `while not stop:`. Also, don't put parentheses around `if` and `while` conditions, always put spaces around keywords, indent continuations like the second like of the `music = ` statement, and indent 4 spaces instead of 8; this makes your code hard to read. See [PEP 8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

The error is with this line:

```
song = random.shuffle(music)
```

`random.shuffle` does not return anything: it reorders the list in place.  The following would work:

```
random.shuffle(music)
song = music[0]
```

Or, more simply:

```
song = random.choice(music)
```

#### Example

This can be tested on the command line:

```
>>> import random
>>> x = range(9)
>>> random.shuffle(x)
>>> x
[1, 4, 2, 3, 0, 5, 6, 7, 8]
>>>
```

Note that the line `random.shuffle(x)` returned nothing.  The list, `x`, though, is now in random order.

Alternatively, using `random.choice`:

```
>>> x = range(9)
>>> random.choice(x)
2
>>> random.choice(x)
6
>>> x
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

With `random.choice`, the list `x` remains in its original order.  Each time `random.choice` is run, a random member of the list is returned.